# Evaluate function on entire PCollection

Tags: apache-beam

I have a `PCollection<V>` that I'd like to essentially evaluate a function `f(List<V>)`. I can make a `CombineFn` that looks like:

```java
class GlobalCombineFn extends Combine.CombineFn<Write, List<Write>, Void> {
    @Override
    public List<Write> createAccumulator() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Write> addInput(List<Write> accumulator, Write input) {
        accumulator.add(input);
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Write> mergeAccumulators(Iterable<List<Write>> accumulators) {
        List<Write> result = createAccumulator();
        accumulators.forEach(result::addAll);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Void extractOutput(List<Write> accumulator) {
        f(accumulator);
        return null;
    }
}
```

However this is kind of silly and a lot of boilerplate. Is there a built-in way to do this?

I also tried using `View.asIterable()`/`View.asList()` however there's not any way to operate on the `PCollectionView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing my own PTransform for this which was substantially simpler:

```java
public class ReduceToIterable<T> extends PTransform<PCollection<T>, PCollection<Iterable<T>>> {
    @Override
    public PCollection<Iterable<T>> expand(PCollection<T> input) {
        return input.apply(WithKeys.of((Void) null))
                .setCoder(KvCoder.of(VoidCoder.of(), input.getCoder()))
                .apply(GroupByKey.create())
                .apply(Values.create());
    }
}
```